# is there a way to automatically update the importfeed function so i can get the most updated news articles from journalists?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've created the importfeed function which gave me the last 20 articles.

```
=importfeed("https://rss.app/feeds/tTDsJYycx4ujEShH.xml?output=atom","items",TRUE,20)
```

I'd like it to update every hour so I can get the fresh new articles that come in.

any help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

in some cell add:

```
=NOW()
```

then select:

[image: 0]